# Set font color in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I have attached my html code.I want to know how to change the font color.

index.html

```
 <html>
 <head>
 ----
 ----
 <body>
 <b>Student Info</b>
 {
 "data": {
 "attributes": {
 "firstName": "xxx",  //view as json data
 "lastName": "yyy"
  ---
  ---
  }}}
   </body></head></html>
```

My output is
     {
     "data":{
     "attributes":{
     "firstname":"xxx"
     "lastname":"yyy"
      }
      }
      }
this my json block view
here how to change the the font color.

Comment: can you explain it properly??

Comment: @user5761830 are you using Angular or what.?

Comment: Add a CSS file, create classes for the keys and values and then put those into spans?

Comment: Don't know what you are trying to do as lots wrong with the code including body tag inside the head http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is some kind of syntax highlighting. I won't give you code that automatically finds keys and values, but I will show you the concept of how it is done.

```css
.value {
  color: red;
}

.key {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<b>Student Info</b>
{<br />
    <span class="key">"data"</span>: {<br />
        <span class="key">"attributes"</span>: {<br />
            <span class="key">"firstName"</span>: <span class="value">"xxx"</span>,<br />
            <span class="key">"lastName"</span>: <span class="value">"yyy"</span><br />
     }<br />
 }
```

Basically you want to add `span` elements to your document and put the keys and values into them. Add CSS classes to the spans which change the color and you are basically done.
Everything else is formatting, as you need the newlines and correct indents.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
<span style="color:#ff0000"> {
     "data": {
     "attributes": {
     "firstName": "xxx",  //view as json data
     "lastName": "yyy"
      ---
      ---
      }}}
    </span>
```